# NSDate change time zone to GMT +02.00

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a `NSDate` with time zone `GMT +00.00` and I want to change it to `GMT +02.00`. To do this, I have created `NSDateFormatter` and set time zone to `UTC` but it does give me expected results,

Here is my code,

```
NSDateFormatter *timeformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeformater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[timeformater setDateFormat:@"EEEE-dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm a"];
[timeformater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

How to change time zone correctly?

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` can't be used to 'change' time zone. If you need to shift `NSDate` by two hours, use `NSCalendar` API.

Comment: ok,but how i can use this and thanks

Answer (score 4):

NSDate is a point in time, independent of time zone. You can't change its time zone, because it doesn't have one. If we are in different areas, and call [NSDate date] at the same time (for example if I call you on the phone and we tap a button at the same moment), we get the same NSDate even though our watches show different times.

NSDateFormatter is used to create strings to display NSDate values, depending on time zone. NSCalendar is used for calculations with NSDate, depending on time zone. But you can't change the timezone of an NSDate.